# 405 Method not allowed when downloading a file from google drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to download a file from google drive, but I get a 405 Method not allowed
I have a valid token and I can upload a file, but downloading it using the fileId from the upload doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/'+fileId);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
  xhr.onload = () => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.response,true,4));
  };
  xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to download a file from Google Drive.
- Your access token can be used for downloading the file from Google Drive using Drive API.

For this, I would like to propose the following modification.

### Modification points:

- I think that in your script, the endpoint of `'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/'+fileId` cannot be used for downloading the file from Google Drive.
- At Google Drive API, the method for downloading the file is different between Google Docs and others. Google Docs files are Google Document, Google Spreadsheet, Google Slides and so on.

From your question, I couldn't understand about the file type you want to download. So in this answer, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

When `fileId` is NOT Google Docs file, you can use the following script. The method of Files: get in Drive API is used. In this case, if the file of file ID is the text file, you can see the file content in the console.

#### Modified script:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + fileId + '?alt=media');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
xhr.onload = () => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.response,true,4));
};
xhr.send();
```

### Pattern 2:

When `fileId` is the Google Docs file which are Google Document, Google Spreadsheet, Google Slides and so on, you can use the following script. The method of Files: export in Drive API is used.

#### Modified script:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + fileId + '/export?mimeType=application%2Fpdf');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
xhr.onload = () => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.response,true,4));
};
xhr.send();
```

- In this case, the Google Docs file is downloaded as a PDF format. When you want to download the file as other mimeType, please set the mimeType.

### Note:

- In above scripts, the file is downloaded as the binary.

### References:

- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)
- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)

Comment: The file is a json file, so not a google doc file, I can upload it without an issue, and I get a fileId back, that I'm using for the download call: 
```GET googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/<fileId>?alt=media``` returns 405 "Method Not Allowed"
```GET googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/<fileId>/export?mimeType=application%2Fjson``` returns 405 "Method Not Allowed"

Comment: Ahhh ... just hit me ... I have upload in the url :-|